# Linked List Data Structure with Javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures, linked-list

I'm trying to figure out the linked list data structure using Javascript. But there is a part that I'm not able to understand.

```
function LinkedList() {
  var Node = function(element) {
    this.element = element;
    this.next = null;
  }

  var length = 0;
  var head = null;

  this.append = function(element) {
    var node = new Node(element),
      current;

    if (head === null) {
      head = node;
    } else {
      current = head;

      //loop the list until find last item
      while (current.next) {
        current = current.next
      }

      //get last item and assign next to node to make the link
      current.next = node
    }
    length++;
  }

  this.removeAt = function(position) {
    //check for out of bounds values
    if (position > -1 && position < length) {
      var current = head,
        previous,
        index = 0;

      if (position === 0) {
        head = current.next;
      } else {
        while (index++ < position) {
          debugger;
          previous = current;
          current = current.next;
        }

        previous.next = current.next;
      }

      length--;

      return current.element;

    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  this.toString = function() {
    var current = head,
      string = '';

    while (current) {
      string = current.element;
      current = current.next;
    }

    return string;
  }
}

var list = new LinkedList();
list.append(15);
list.append(10);
list.append(11);
list.removeAt(1);
```

I don't  understand how the variable ***current*** loses its reference to the node when you run the *removeAt* method.

Comment: Please format your code with some whitespace - it's hard to parse without formatting, and less likely you will receive help.

Comment: When you say "... current loses its reference to the node..." are you asking how/why the node is deleted?

Comment: *current* is a variable local to your *removeAt* method, so what exactly is the problem you see? I checked your code, and it seems all OK, except maybe that the *toString* method only returns the content of the tail node. Could you add code that demonstrates the issue you see? Something that produces a result you did not expect or desire?

Comment: @nurdyguy yes that's the part I don't get

Comment: @marquezgon When you take the `previous` node and set his next to `current.next` using `previous.next = current.next` the result is that `previous` now links directly to the node **after** `current`.  Thus you have removed `current` from the list.  Then at the end of the function the `current` variable goes out of scope and is effectively deleted.

Comment: I've done pretty similar implementation and described it here https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-create-linked-list-in-javascript-with-es6-classes/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create the link list you can use the below algorithm:-

```
var linkedList = function(){
  this.head=null;
  this.tail=null;
  this.size=0;
}
linkedList.prototype.add=function(obj){
 if(!this.head){
   this.head=obj;
   this.tail=obj;
   this.size++;
   return
 }
 this.tail.next = obj;
 this.tail=obj;
 this.size++;
}
```